# jquery set cursor to first character of textarea

Tags: jquery, focus, textarea, character

I have custom placeholders in a textarea and I would like every browser to move the cursor to the first character of that placeholder as soon as the user clicks it or focuses in on it.

How can I achieve that? I have no idea so no code posted.

Thanks!

Dennis

EDIT 1

This is the textarea:

```
<textarea id="posttext"> Post something...</textarea><br/>
```

And this is the code to remove " Post something...":

```
//Placeholder in posttext
$('#posttext').keydown(function(){
if($(this).val()==' Post something...') $(this).val('').css('color','black');
}).blur(function(){
    if($(this).val()=='') $(this).val(' Post something...').css('color','grey');
});
```

Comment: [you are going to have to show a little bit more effort](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/102937)... people are not going to do your work for you...

Comment: I don't understand what your "placeholders in a textarea" are.

Comment: @Lix You are right - please see question edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('#posttext').on('focus', function() {
    if($(this).val() == ' Post something...') {
        $(this).val('').css('color','black');
    }
}).blur(function() {
    if($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).val(' Post something...').css('color','grey');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="posttext"> Post something...</textarea>
```

Comment: Nope, not quite... I need the placeholder to stay until the user actually types something.